# how to restore last helm session?

Tags: helm, buffers

Is there a way to reopen the last `helm` buffer including minibuffer content and cursor position ? This would be especially convenient, when using `helm-find-files` to navigate remote filesystems.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `helm-resume` to resume last helm session, and with prefix argument, you can even list all past helm sessions that can be resumed. See also https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Resume.